# Lock table before inserting into it

Tags: sql-server-2008, insert, network-programming, locking

I created a C# application that works with network. And I use SQL Server 2008 Express for my application.

**My problem is:**

When 2 people on 2 computers at exactly the same time click on the `Insert` button, 2 rows are added into the database with the same number (that is the fault).

If time does not same, my application check some conditions and this problem will not occur.

**My question is:**

Now I want lock table before insert for 1 person and unlock table after insert.

How to do this?

Comment: How are you managing the primary key? What you are seeing is likely due to bad practice at the table definition. Likely you should let the DB manage the primary keys...

Comment: I Know. i  Make ID column that is Primary Column, But For Some Reason i Have Another Column That Must Be Primary in This Case.

Comment: One word: ***DON'T DO THIS!*** You need to **fix** your routine that defines the *number* that causes the problem. Locking the whole table is **NOT** the solution to your problem!

Comment: The **easiest** solution is to use a column of type `INT IDENTITY` - then SQL Server will automatically handle the numbering, and SQL Server will **guarantee** that are **no duplicates** no matter how many people click your `Insert` button at the same time.

Comment: INT IDENTITY is Good Idea . But my problem is that when active «Is Identity» For My Column. Auto Increment active too. but i want myself select value for this column.

Comment: If you want to assign this value yourself, you are going to have a bad time. Realize that when the table is locked it is locked for all the other users as well. How are you going to manage that? This isn't a good idea at all...

Comment: **WHY** do you need to select that value yourself?? What's the business case / requirement for this? It's just a consecutive number.... I don't care what those numbers are - as long as they're guaranteed to be unique for each row!

Comment: Now I Did This Work: Set IS_IDENTITY For «ID» Column - And Set Primary For «Another» Column. And Now almost Problem is Solve. But I Want In Some Case Save Same Number For «Another» Column. that with this situation Can't Do this.

Answer (score 0):

you have to Use IDENTITY column .

if you want  lock the table  in sql server  you can  do  like this

```
INSERT INTO Table1 WITH (TABLOCK)
SELECT @Col1, @Col2, @Col3, @Col4 OPTION (FAST 1)

UPDATE Table1 WITH (TABLOCK) 
SET Col5 = @Col5
WHERE @Col1 = @Var

UPDATE Table2 WITH (TABLOCK) 
SET Col = @ColVal
```